# Isolated Tests Are Not Being Run At Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, spock

I run my Spock (v 2.4-M1-groovy-3.0) tests with Maven inside of the Docker container at Jenkins. The problem is that sometimes (not always) tests are stuck: `mvn clean test` command just freezes after some random test and doesn't go further and there is no errors at all in any logs. And it happens only at Jenkins, I can't reproduce it locally.

I figured out that all regular tests are run (in parallel) and all `@Isolated` tests are "waiting to be run", but they never will. The number of parallel threads is not regulated and it can be 19, but in some cases it can be 25, so 19 is not the max capacity. Anyway, if the problem was in the resources then sooner on later they would be vacant, but it doesn't happened in a days.

Can anyone relate to this problem?